# Solving the error TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, inheritance

I am very new to programming. Here is my simple code below

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 10

        def add(self):
            c = self.value + 10
            print("the sum is:")
            print(c)

class InheritingClass(BaseClass):
    pass

x = InheritingClass(BaseClass)
```

I am working on inheritance with python. When I run this script I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python/classes_01.py", line 20, in <module>
    x = InheritingClass(BaseClass)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Does any one have an idea on this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to pass `BaseClass` to the constructor. Simply do

```
x = InheritingClass()
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create the `InheritingClass` object with:

```
x = InheritingClass()
```

**Why?** Because the super class is already specified in the class definition:

```
class InheritingClass(BaseClass):
    pass
```

so it's not necessary to specify it again.

Comment: why not adding `value` to `__init__`'s arguments ? as the error is because of it ?

Comment: Because he is passing `BaseClass` as argument, which doesn't make sense at all. Unless he wants to use it inside the code, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you coded the line:

```
class InheritingClass(BaseClass):
```

you were indicating that Inheriting class inherits from BaseClass (i.e. is a sub-class of). You did not give any information about how to create an instance of InheritingClass. That information is in the **init** method.

In this case, InheritingClass inherits its __init__ method from BaseClass, where there are no user supplied inputs specified/required. Just use

```
x = InheritingClass()
```

to create an instance of InheritingClass, the same way you would use

```
x2 = BaseClass()
```

to create an instance of BaseClass

Answer (score 1):

Like it's already been said, just write x = InheritingClass()

Remember: Every method of a class has at least 1 parameter, and that's *self*.
That's why you always have to write self in the method definition of a class. But when you
call the function you don't have to pass self to the function:

```
class A:
    ...
    def foo(self):
        print "bla"

    ...


#call foo
a = A()
a.foo() # self is implicitly there
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` has to be added to the arguments of the constructor method of 
`__init__`. 
Also you should have declared the `value` not as an instance but as a class variable. It would've helped with code readability